# JavaScript | Не срабатывает setTimeout();

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. У меня возникла проблема, с методом который я указал в заголовке. Код на картинке.

Мне нужно, что бы после нажатия кнопки пользователем на сайте, нужная функция выполнилась через 5.3 секунды. Я опробовал много методам со стаковерфлоу и других подобных тематических форумах по решению данной проблемы. Ничего не помогает.
В дебаге, интерпретатор доходит до setTimeout и дальше код просто перестает срабатывать, без ошибок и предупреждений. В дескрипторе OnClick функцию js объявить не смогу, так как по нему работает сервер на c#.
Помогите пожалуйста, решить данную проблему. И в общем, целом говоря, каким образом вы реализовываете подобные действия как при нажатии на кнопку запустить функцию через некоторое время? И я скажу какие из этих реализаций я уже пробовал.

```js
let attemtVariable = document.getElementById("ImageButton2");

document.getElementById("ImageButton1").addEventListener("mousedown", her);
function her()
{
    event.preventDefault();
    var winLabel = document.getElementById("Label");
    if(winLabel.style.display = "none")
    {
        setTimeout(function () { winLabel.style.display = "block";  }, 5400)
    }
}

let cookie = document.cookie = encodeURIComponent("STAT") + "=" + encodeURIComponent("yh123mx4832pq030304");
attemtVariable.onclick = swimWindow;

function swimWindow() {
    console.log("Test win");

    var ReturnDef = event.preventDefault();

    if (cookie = "STAT=yh123mx4832pq030304") {
        var divWin = document.getElementById("dinamicBlock");

        if (divWin.style.display = "none") {
            statWin = divWin.style.display = "block";
        }
        else
            statWin = divWin.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
body {
    background-image: url('../images/BGimage.jpg');
    padding: 30px;
    position: absolute; 
}
.basicBlock {
    position: fixed;
    width: 1840px;
    height: 850px;
    margin: 2px
}
.elementsBlock {
    float: left;
    height: 840px;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 3px;
    color: #e0ab00;
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 30px;
    border: 2px hidden #00ff21;
}
.elementsBlock2 {
    float: left;
    height: 840px;
    width: 1014px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.elementsBlock3 {
    float: right;
    width: 400px;
    height: 840px;
    margin: 3px;
}
.gameblockBG {
    background-image: url('../images/BGWheel.png');
    margin: 0px auto;
    height: 512px;
    width: 512px;
    position:absolute;
    left: 660px;
    top: 70px;
    z-index: 2;
}
.buttomstyle {
    background-image: url('../images/Button.png');
    height: 63px;
    padding: 1px;
    width: 125px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 550px;
    left: 190px;  
}
    .buttomstyle:hover {
        background-image: url('../images/Button_click.png');
        height: 63px;
        padding: 1px;
        width: 125px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 550px;
        left: 190px;
    }
.buttomstyle1 {
    background-image: url('../images/Button1.png');
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 250px;
    left: 10px;
    top: 60px;
}
    .buttomstyle1:hover {
        background-image: url('../images/Button1_click.png');
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        height: 50px;
        width: 250px;
        left: 10px;
        top: 60px;
    }
.wheelstart {
    background-image: url('../images/123.PNG');
    animation-name: twister;
    transform: rotate(380deg);
    height: 402px;
    width: 502px;
}
.information {
    position: inherit;
    top: 15px;
    left: 130px;
    border: 4px double #ffffff;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
.MyInfoImg {
    background-image: url('../images/blockWin.png');
    position: fixed;
    width: 500px;
    height: 150px;
    top: 300px;
}
.attempt {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 110px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 150px;
}
.result {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    font-size: 90px;
    left: 40px;
    top: -100px;
}
.dinamicBlock {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99999;
    background-color: white;
    border: 4px groove #808080;
    height: 700px;
    width: 1300px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    opacity: 0.95;
    left: 300px;
    top: 100px;
    display: none;
    color: #ff6a00;
    font-size: 40px;
}
.inputNik {
    position: absolute;
    left: 305px;
    top: 400px;
    color: blue;
    font: 400;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 70px;
    text-align:center;
}
.infoNic {
    position:absolute;
    top: 350px;
    left: 400px;
}
.dinamicCount {
    position: absolute;
    top: 180px;
    left: 610px;
    font-size: 125px;
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #ff0000;
}
.buttonNext {
    position: absolute;
    top: 560px;
    left: 570px;
    background-color: #d8351f;
    color: white;
    width: 180px;
    height: 70px;
    font-size: 50px;
}


<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><link href="ViewFiles/css/styleblock.css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="ViewFiles/css/animation.css" rel="stylesheet" /><title>
    
</title></head>

<body class ="body" id="bodyID">

    <form method="post" action="./MainPage.aspx" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="bP08pd1GVY/X5ClqX7DUmr/XYFc1ohYWLVDyWDW2ZSGzoKMGyOljliGJ31ZEyKKjeuqUPo+GutkqL+dKQtgQRF2Vlz1V1UvxRr/nog85c8XnquUGS7ClMQNKGHdeADIf5QZPt3461T4sD4aBF1Z/56kxkbmMHP08ZQMReCMnegCNa52brKJ7mb4cdv0h0EFB" />
</div>


    <div class ="basicBlock">

        <div class ="elementsBlock">

            <div class="MyInfoImg" id ="MyInfoImg" >

                <div class="attempt">  
                    <span id="Label1">У вас 3 попытки</span>                 
                    <span id="Label" class="result">0</span>
                    <input type="image" name="ImageButton2" id="ImageButton2" class="buttomstyle1" src="ViewFiles/images/pixAlphaForbutton.png" /> 
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class ="elementsBlock2 ">

            <div class ="gameblockBG">

                <div id="rotate" class="forcircle">

                    <input type="image" name="ImageButton1" id="ImageButton1" class="buttomstyle" src="ViewFiles/images/pixAlphaForbutton.png" />
                    <img id="ImageWheel" class="staticPosition" src="ViewFiles/images/FWheel.PNG" /> 
                    
                    
                    >        
                </div>

            </div>

            
        </div>

        <div class ="elementsBlock3">3</div>

        <div class="dinamicBlock" id ="dinamicBlock">
            <span id="Lab" style="position:absolute; left: 435px; top: 50px; font-size: 65px;">Ваш выигрыш:</span>
            <span id="Label3" class="dinamicCount">0</span>
            <span class="infoNic">Введите свой ник в Roblox:</span>
            <input class="inputNik" id="Text1" type="text"/>
            <input type="submit" name="Button1" value="Далее" id="Button1" class="buttonNext" />
        </div>
        <script src="ViewFiles/js/transition.js"></script>
    </div>       
    
<div class="aspNetHidden">

    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="0C7D29E3" />
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="+zs2Z5zTyrSOsee+jrNNIr2IMfgap4t4PYK1me/wg1GKTmuzyb5sizf2n2MTeKlfnnSjBcd7TaN2wxhT2fQkxrFcZzKpY0Hel3PVRhIu4vqivSazTk6wFv0TwhtlRbLhxcP6JySqBHTCqiZ6m6DZtn12RZVpcmGU1wrpwy9Aaf0=" />
</div></form> 
    

<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://localhost:44399/a76549cb6a9646ddb047b131ea0354b1/browserLink" async="async" id="__browserLink_initializationData" data-requestId="c48c0f02ee6d48d2857bf4bc4674b650" data-appName="Chrome"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: приложите весь ваш код, html/js текстом, не картинкой.

Comment: `getElementById` принимает на вход один параметр. А у вас там запятая

Comment: И для начала исправьте хотя бы очевидные ошибки. Например, попытку обращения к несуществующей переменной event и присваивание внутри if

Comment: @andreymal по умолчанию эта переменная видна, если она вызвана слушателем события

Comment: @АлексейШиманский исправил, ничего не решило

Comment: @МихаилКамахин приложил

Comment: Вячеслав, редактор stackoverflow умеет понимать только html/css/js, я не знаю c# или на чём это написано, поэтому я не понимаю html этот (может и могу понять, но не хочу париться). Вы можете зайти в инспектор браузера и скопировать весь html, который генерирует браузер.

Comment: @МихаилКамахин исправил

Comment: @МихаилКамахин «по умолчанию эта переменная видна» — хм, как-то не очень надёжно полагаться на переменную, которая объявлена непонятно где и легко перекрывается банальным var event в любом месте скрипта...

Comment: `if(winLabel.style.display = "none")`  у вас вместо условия присваивание.

Comment: @AlexeyTen и вроде таким способом не прочитать значения, для этого нужно использовать getComputedStyle

Comment: @МихаилКамахин "по умолчанию эта переменная видна, если она вызвана слушателем события" - удивительный миф

Comment: @AlexeyTen исправил, не помогло

Comment: @МихаилКамахин если убрать setTimeout функция срабатывает, только мне нужно что бы прошло определенное время.

Comment: @ВячеславШабунин Уберите присваивания из всех условий в `if`.

Comment: @Igor функция swimWindow работает прекрасно, у меня с ней проблем нет. И потом как мне тогда проверять какое свойство css присвоено?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle